# Eclipses - C language - Debug - any way to view values pointed on by pointers?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

Using Eclipse, working with (ANSI) C language, is there any way to view the values that pointers are pointing on from debug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `printf` to print the values you need at the places you want to check them.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Eclipse in years, but isn't there a "watch" window, where you can add variables to watch? In that case you should be able to just put `*pointer` in there.